# How to add Google Tag Manager firing rule for Backbone Marionette site?

Tags: backbone.js, google-analytics, marionette, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I have already built a site with backbone marionette and now I am trying to use Google Tag manager to add the tracking. But I have no idea how to configure GTM, in order to listen page change and button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicks are up to you to set up listening events and track manually from views. Page views can be tracked like this:

```
Backbone.history.on('route', function() {
  // Send Backbone.history.fragment to your page view tracker
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of fiddling required there.
Tag manager uses a data structure called `dataLayer`. It's an array, that you can add events to.
So to configure tag manager, you need to add a snippet to HTML page of the application as in any other case. On top of it, you have to initialise the dataLayer array but you need to make sure, that **the code initialising this variable is invoked before the snippet**.
So here is the full example in the head of the index.html page (in one page app):

```
<html>
<head>
... 
<script>
  dataLayer = [];
</script>
<script>
function loadProductDetails(productIdentifier) {
dataLayer.push({
  'event':'pageview',
  'virtualUrl':'/product/'+productIdentifier 
});
// code to load product details and display to user
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-3VLTP"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-3VLTP');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
...
<a onclick="loadProductDetails('nexus7');">Nexus 7</a>
...
</body>
</html>
```

The function called `loadProductDetails` is an example on how you push the events to Google servers - you just need to add an object to the dataLayer array.

Dan Russel wrote a full [blog post](http://dan-russell.com/2013/07/google-tag-manager-for-single-page-applications/) about it, together with explanation how to setup the macro for extracting the events.

And there is a bit of documentation on this as well [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide)