# How to use Google Tag Manager with Backbone router to track page views?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Facing problem while tracking page views in Backbone router, where exactly should I place the code snippet from google tag manager.

Comment: I answered this question in another thread. Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419032/4835114).

Answer (score -1):

Wait until `onDOMContentLoaded` or `document.ready` your entry point script like `main.js` then kick off your app and run the snippet after that. Id usually do something like:

```
function onDOMContentLoaded() {

    // Kick off App
    App.initialize();

    setTimeout(function() {
        loadAnalytics();
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about on `route` event?

```
Backbone.history.on('route', function() { 
    #gtm code here 
}, this);
```